# Appending data (array) into excel elementwise by using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

Appending array into excel columns elementwise

I am trying to automate my excel console sheet using python/pandas and numpy. I have already read the excel, converted data into arrays, did the matrix ops. and now I am getting row vector of [1x6] which I want to append into 6 columns. How to do this in pandas as I am very new in python!

````
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
s= pd.read_excel('ECOMP TRACKING.xlsx',sheet_name='SCHEDULE') #imprt as dataset
S = s.to_numpy() #converts to ndarray
veh = np.array(S[:,0])[np.newaxis] #gives 1xn matrix
V_sch=(S[:,1:])
e= pd.read_excel('ECOMP TRACKING.xlsx',sheet_name='EBOM')
E= e.to_numpy()
veh1 = np.array(E[:,2])[np.newaxis]  #gives 1xn matrix
#BO=B_0.T
b_1= veh1.size
i=0
while i<b_1:
    if veh1[0][i]==veh[0][0]:
        P1_sch=pd.ExcelWriter np.multiply(V_sch[0][:],E[i][5]*E[i][6])

        i+=1
    elif veh1[0][i]==veh[0][1]:
        P2_sch= np.multiply(V_sch[1][:],E[i][5]*E[i][6])
        i+=1
    elif veh1[0][i]==veh[0][2]:
        P3_sch= np.multiply(V_sch[2][:],E[i][5]*E[i][6])
        i+=1
    elif veh1[0][i]==veh[0][3]:
        P4_sch= np.multiply(V_sch[3][:],E[i][5]*E[i][6])
        i+=1
    elif veh1[0][i]==veh[0][4]:
        P5_sch= np.multiply(V_sch[4][:],E[i][5]*E[i][6])
        i+=1
    elif veh1[0][i]==veh[0][5]:
        P6_sch= np.multiply(V_sch[5][:],E[i][5]*E[i][6])
        i+=1
    else:
        i+=1```

I want to store each instance of P1_sch, P2_sch,.... into cells
````

Comment: You might want to edit your post to provide more detail. Include the code you're using and the results you have so far so people can understand what you're trying to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

For your first vector, i.e. names of your columns, you might want to write:

```
df.columns = arr
```

For all the others:

```
df.append(arr)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Comment: yeah but my vector is an array, do I have to covert into dataframe again?

Comment: You can directly append an array to a dataframe